# Create token in laravel passport without verify auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I already use login by active directory and after verify username and password from active directory if correct I want to create access `token` in `laravel` passport. But I can't create token without verify `Auth` in `laravel`.

I try **this code** after verify from active directory

```
$success['token'] =  createToken($email)->accessToken;
```

**Error**:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\API\createToken()

How to create access token in `laravel` passport without using `Auth`?

Comment: do you have a answer? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

After Successfully Login attempt you can create token like.

```
if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid credentials']);
        }
$accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

OR

```
$user = User::find($id);
$accessToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

Comment: i didn't use auth, user login by Active directory so i didn't have auth.